# Implementation of search function of Sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, sequelize.js

Before the question, the **`post`** table of my current project has the following structure.

```
module.exports = class Post extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({      
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
      },     
      desc: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,        
      },      
      ingredient: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
      },     
      recipes: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
      },     
      tips: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,        
      },     
      tags: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,        
      },      
    }, {
      modelName: 'Post',
      tableName: 'posts',
      charset: 'utf8mb4',
      collate: 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
      sequelize,
    });
  }
  static associate(db) {
    db.Post.belongsTo(db.User);
    db.Post.belongsToMany(db.Hashtag, { through: 'PostHashtag' });
    db.Post.hasMany(db.Comment);
    db.Post.hasMany(db.Image);
    db.Post.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'Like', as: 'Likers' });    
  }
};
```

I implemented the **`hashtag`** **`post`** search function using the following router.

```
router.get('/:tag', async (req, res, next) => {/hashtag/1
  try {
    const where = {};
    if (parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)) {
      where.id = { [Op.lt]: parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)};      
    }
    const posts = await Post.findAll({
      where,
      limit: 10,      
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],      
      include: [{
        model: Hashtag,
        where: { name: decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag) },
      }, {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
      }, {
        model: User,
        as: 'Likers',
        attributes: ['id'],
      }, {
        model: Comment,
        include: [{
          model: User,
          attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
        }],
      }, {
        model: Image,
      }]
    });
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

The execution result was successful, and I was able to get the results I wanted.

However, we thought that it was not enough to search only hashtags, so we added the following conditions to additionally search the **`title`** and **`contents`** of the post.

```
router.get('/:tag', async (req, res, next) => { 
  try {
    const where = {
      title: { [Op.like]: "%" + decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag) + "%" }, // Search for the title of a post     
      recipes: { [Op.like]: "%" + decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag) + "%" }, // Search the content of the post
    };
    if (parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)) {
      where.id = { [Op.lt]: parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10)};      
    }
    const posts = await Post.findAll({
      where,
      limit: 10,    
                      :
                      :
```

After that, the result of running the code did not load any posts, contrary to what I expected.

What part should be modified to implement a search function that includes the title, content, and hashtag of a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem with your function is that you are using `where` with **AND**
instead of **OR**.

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: 
   [{ title: {[Op.like]...} }, 
   { recipes: {[Op.like]...} }], // (title= %S) AND (recipes = %S)
...
)} 

// that is the same as your example

const where = {
    // Search for the title of a post     
      title: { [Op.like]: "%"..., 
    // Search the content of the post
      recipes: { [Op.like]: "%"... }, 
    };
// this is an AND operation
```

What you should do is use **OR**. More info: [operators](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators)

```
[Op.or]: [{ a: 5 }, { b: 6 }],             // (a = 5) OR (b = 6)
```

In your case:

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: 
   [{ title: {[Op.like]...} }, 
   { recipes: {[Op.like]...} }], // (title= %S) AND (recipes = %S)
...
)}
```

That is also not the proper way of searching.  Maybe you should consider looking for full-text search implementations like Elastic Search or look if the database you are using has this feature built-in.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I was thinking about has been solved.

Comment: Based on your advice, I modified the code as follows: But still couldn't get any data.

Do you have any problems with the code I wrote?

Comment: const where = {
      [Op.or]: [
        { title: { [Op.like]: \`%${decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag)}%` } },
        { desc: { [Op.like]: \`%${decodeURIComponent(req.params.tag)}%` } },
      ],
    };

Comment: @Clloud I do not have any problem with that code above. You should try first with one property and then another. Search without Op.or only title and search without Op.or only tag. See if they return results.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll implement your advice.